# runtime error when saving user generated image to core data (Swift5)

Tags: core-data, imageview, option-type, swift5, binary-image

I am trying to save a user generated image to core data. If I program the image the code works fine. But when the user selects the image I am getting the error **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** at **jx = drawPlace.image!**. I just want to fix that and the code will work. It is not having any problems saving into core data just the wrapping.

```
    var jx = UIImage()
var drawPlace = UIImageView()
func save() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedContext)!

    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)


    jx = drawPlace.image!
    if let data = jx.pngData() {
        item.setValue(data, forKey: "image")
    }
```

Comment: Try `if let data = drawPlace.image?.pngData() {`

Comment: When I change it to that code I got the runtime error of Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on     jx = drawPlace.image! So something changes but it seems like the same problem.

Comment: If you look at my code you see that I have included that part so remove that line completely

Comment: Thats it. Golden